# Will using System.IO.StreamWriter & WriteLineAsync wait for a file that is being accessed by another thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc-5 web application :-

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file =
new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/logs/logs.txt"), true);
await file.WriteLineAsync("execution started at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
file.Close();
```

now my question what will happen if 2 methods execute the above code at the same time? will one of them fail ? since it will be trying to write to the txt file which is being accessed by another thread ?

Comment: You really should be using a `using` statement so your file will be closed even if a exception is thrown from the `WriteLineAsync`.

Comment: Logging is a solved problem. Unless this is out of idle curiosity, I suggest you use one of the several existing logging libraries and move on to something something more important.

Comment: If it is out of idle curiosity, don't have many writers. Have a single writer and have it take its data from a queue. New messages go in the queue.

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this very nicely for you such that you get a queue and a mechanism by which writes to the file never occur in parallel (by using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`)

```
public class Logger
{
    private ActionBlock<string> block;
    public Logger(string filePath)
    {
        block = new ActionBlock<string>(async message => {
            using(var f = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                f.Position = f.Length;
                using(var sw = new StreamWriter(f))
                {
                    await sw.WriteLineAsync(message);
                }
            }
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1});
    }
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        block.Post(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the explicit `Flie.Open` instead of using the string overload `StreamWriter` provides?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was struggling with overwriting... thinking about the streamwriter method, it was probably unnecessary as IIRC it has overloads around this, but there are a lot of options that OP might want to take up (for instance that might allow `tail`ing the log) that might (or might not) be set by the StreamWriter, so I thought explicitness was handy here. Otherwise known as reluctance to RTFM.

Answer (score 2):

When you open `StreamWriter` with a string [it does the following](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,224) to create the stream

```
private static Stream CreateFile(String path, bool append, bool checkHost) {
    FileMode mode = append? FileMode.Append: FileMode.Create;
    FileStream f = new FileStream(path, mode, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read,
        DefaultFileStreamBufferSize, FileOptions.SequentialScan, Path.GetFileName(path), false, false, checkHost);
    return f;
}
```

Because it does `FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read` that means it is asking for write permission and only allow other people to open the file if they are asking for read permission. Because both calls will be asking for write permission the 2nd call will fail with a "file in use" error.

---

A way to work around this issue is use a [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) to block access to the file, this will only allow one writer at a time.

```
//Elsewhere
private static SemaphoreSlim _fileLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);


//In your function.
try
{
    await _fileLock.WaitAsync();
    using(var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/logs/logs.txt"), true))
    {
        await file.WriteLineAsync("execution started at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
finally
{
    _fileLock.Release();
}
```

However a even better solution is just find a 3rd party logging library that can handle this for you like [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), then you don't need to worry about the locking or concurrency.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Because `lock(lockObject)` is a syncronous lock, the OP is using async/await so I went with a async lock. Had he been using `WriteLine` instead of `WriteLineAsync` I would have used just  a normal `lock`.

Comment: Rather than preventing concurrency, I find it's always better to design something that doesn't need to deal with it in the first place. Queue based architechtures ftw. After all, concurrent writes to the drive never work out too well.

Comment: OK, I missed the await in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will get an error that the file is in use by another process.  Your best bet is to surround that block with`try catch` and handle the exception then retry once the file is available.