# C# Method ignoring async await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I still get `System.IO.IOException` telling me the file is used in another process, even thought I use `async` `await` and `SemaphoreSlim` `WaitAsync` and `Release` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38508032/5825579). I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong?

In class outside my method I have

```
private static SemaphoreSlim FileLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
```

The method using `async` and `await`

```
public async void Write(params string[] text)
    {
        try
        {
            await FileLock.WaitAsync();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(this.Source, true)) // <- IOException
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                {
                    await sw.WriteAsync(text[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            FileLock.Release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should you wait for all the write operations before exiting the scope?

Comment: This might prevent simultaneous writes from within your process, but doesn't prevent some external process from locking the file. Maybe that is the case?

Comment: SemaphoreSlim limits the number of *threads* and async/await doesn't necessarily use different threads.